# How to use eBay api to add our own products to sell on eBay using php?

Tags: php, ebay-api

I have a web application on which I am selling my own products. I want to implement the functionality of adding my products on eBay store using eBay API. I want to get the products from my database and upload that products to eBay if the admin clicks on 'Upload to eBay' button. how should I achieve this ? I read the API documentation of eBay, but got more confused after reading it. I don't know how to start, if I get any help with the demos than would be great.

Comment: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=ebay+api+php+example. Enjoy!

Comment: Did you develop your web application, or is it from a vendor? Do you have any programming knowledge? Your first step may be to hire a consultant if reading documentation is more confusing rather than helpful.

Comment: No we have develop that application ourselves. I am a developer, but have very little knowledge to work on back end and external APIs.

Comment: @RisPeterson The easiest way is to use production ready SDK, like this one: https://github.com/davidtsadler/ebay-sdk-php.

Comment: try it out, ebay-sdk is what i use and it helps. if you need pointers once in there, post a specific question and reference it on this comment thread. ill help u out

Comment: @RalphThomasHopper Sure I'll give it a try and get back to you here. Thanks.

Comment: @RalphThomasHopper I tried using SDK. I am stuck at one point as I am getting an error, which I am not able to solve. If you can, than please have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/q/48815105/8229705 .