# ClientException: Client Error giving '401 Unauthorized' error in GuzzleHttp while using eBay SDK api using Php

Tags: php, ebay-api

I am using eBay SDK for Inventory API using php. While running the following code, I am getting the error saying ClientExcemption with some '401 Unauthorized' error code. I have downloaded zip of eBay SDK and unzip it in my vendor folder.

Below is the code I wrote:

**config.php**

```
<?php
return [ 
    'sandbox' => [
        'credentials' => [
            'devId' => 'my devID',
            'appId' => 'my appID',
            'certId' => 'my certID',
        ],
        'authToken' => 'myauthToken',
        'oauthUserToken' => 'my oauthUserToken',                
        'ruName' => 'my ruName'
    ]
];
?>
```

In **controller.php**, the following is the code for ebay feed:

```
$config = require __DIR__.'/../config.php';
require './vendor/ebay-sdk-php/ebay-sdk-php-autoloader.php';
use \DTS\eBaySDK\Inventory\Services;
use \DTS\eBaySDK\Inventory\Types;
use \DTS\eBaySDK\Inventory\Enums;

public function ebay_feed($save = true){
    $service = new Services\InventoryService([
        'authorization'    => $config['sandbox']['oauthUserToken'],
        'requestLanguage'  => 'en-US',
        'responseLanguage' => 'en-US',
        'sandbox'          => true,
        'httpOptions'      => [
            'verify' => false
        ]    
    ]);



$request = new Types\CreateOrReplaceInventoryItemRestRequest();

    $request->sku = '123';

    $request->availability = new Types\Availability();
    $request->availability->shipToLocationAvailability = new Types\ShipToLocationAvailability();
    $request->availability->shipToLocationAvailability->quantity = 50;

    $request->condition = Enums\ConditionEnum::C_NEW_OTHER;

    $request->product = new Types\Product();
    $request->product->title = 'Honda';
    $request->product->description = 'New';

    $request->product->aspects = [
        'Brand'                => ['Honda'],
        'Type'                 => ['Vehicles'],
        'Storage Type'         => ['Removable'],
        'Recording Definition' => ['High Definition'],
        'Media Format'         => ['Flash Drive (SSD)'],
        'Optical Zoom'         => ['10x', '8x', '4x']
    ];

    $request->product->imageUrls = [
        'http://i.ebayimg.com/images/i/182196556219-0-1/s-l1000.jpg',
        'http://i.ebayimg.com/images/i/182196556219-0-1/s-l1001.jpg',
        'http://i.ebayimg.com/images/i/182196556219-0-1/s-l1002.jpg'
    ];

    $response = $service->createOrReplaceInventoryItem($request);

    printf("\nStatus Code: %s\n\n", $response->getStatusCode());
    if (isset($response->errors)) {
        foreach ($response->errors as $error) {
            printf(
                "%s: %s\n%s\n\n",
                $error->errorId,
                $error->message,
                $error->longMessage
            );
        }
    }
    if ($response->getStatusCode() >= 200 && $response->getStatusCode() < 400) {
        echo "Success\n";
    }
}
```

The following error that I get when I try to run my code.

How to solve this error ?

[image]

Comment: Hi Ris, try using this guide to fetch your OAuth token. it should help you
https://ebaydts.com/eBayKBDetails?KBid=5075

Comment: @RalphThomasHopper I did try this. Didn't work yet

Comment: well, right now, a non-authorized error would mean you are not getting auth and user tokens. if you are using composer (which you should if starting a new project), install the sdk using composer... that will take care of any dependency you may not be fulfilling. second, start by using simple examples provided within the repo. the simple webapp is a great place to start
https://github.com/davidtsadler/ebay-sdk-examples/blob/master/oauth-tokens/slim-app.php

Comment: i am sorry i cannot be of more help right now but the provided information is insufficient for me to grasp exactly what goes wrong in your auth. i think you may be thinking auth tokens are a 1 shot deal. but they need to be refreshed. they are temps.